# How to join multiple tables with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have six tables

online_transaction

`| date | id | supplier_id | product code |`

online_transaction_enc

`| date | id | item |`

offline_transaction

`| date | id |`

offline_transaction_enc

`| date | id | item |`

products

`| type | product_code |`

supplier

`| supplier_id | country |`

> Select count(item) where date is between '2018-Jun-01' And '2018-July-30' AND Type='household' AND country='Malaysia'

These is roughly what I want to achieve. I want to union item from online and offline on date and id so I will get all items combine and then followed by the other requirements.
How can do this in MySQL ?

Comment: You mentioned `join` in your question's title - you should take a look at the syntax for a `JOIN` in MySQL and give it a go.

Comment: I don't see a relation for country. Is there a country_id or supplier_id in one of these tables?

Comment: @Dan oh, yes. There's a supplier _id. let me edit that in.

Comment: 6 tables?? and 2 are duplicate name, how come? anything missed or wrong?

Comment: Yes, sorry. There's a different table for online and offline sales although they have the same content in the table

Comment: so, you want to get the count of (item) online and offline both between given date where type is household and country is malaysia?

Comment: @DeepakSharma Yes, correct

Comment: its not clear what exactly you are looking for.  this statement is very generic.  Provide your expected result and some input data, that will let us know your exact need

Comment: You also mention UNION. Between JOIN and UNION, I think you have your answer, but if you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 select count(a.item) from 
    (select date, id, item from online_transaction_enc
    union 
    select date, id, item from offline_transaction_enc)a
    inner join 
    (
    select  date,id,supplier_id,productcode from online_transaction
    union 
    select  date,id,supplier_id,productcode from offline_transaction)b
    on a.date=b.date and a.id=b.id
    inner join supplier on b.supplier_id=supplier.supplier_id
    inner join products on b.productcode=products.product_code
    where a.date between '20180601' And '20180730' AND Type='household' AND country='Malaysia'
```

Comment: This is exactly what im looking for. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT count(item)
FROM online_transaction_enc
INNER JOIN online_transaction_enc ON supplier_id
INNER JOIN products ON supplier_id
...
WHERE WHERE (date BETWEEN '2010-01-30 14:15:55' AND '2010-09-29 10:15:55')
;
```

This solution is using an inner join. I believe this is what you're looking for. Here is more documentation 
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx

Comment: You will need to edit the long date to fit your range.